# Connecting to Cassandra with Java driver, getting error "local DC must be explicitly set"

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I try to create a connection using given paramters.

```
CqlSessionBuilder builder = CqlSession.builder();
        int port = 9042;
        for ( String host : hosts ){
            int idx = host.indexOf(":");
            if ( idx > 0 ){
                port = Integer.parseInt( host.substring( idx +1).trim() );
                host = host.substring( 0, idx ).trim();
            }
            builder.addContactPoint( new InetSocketAddress( host, port ) );
            if (sslEnabled) {
                //builder.withSSL();
            }
        }
        if ( dataCenter != null ) builder.withLocalDatacenter( dataCenter );
        if ( userName != null && !userName.isEmpty() && password != null ) {
            builder.withAuthCredentials(userName, password);
        }
        return builder.build();
```

When connecting, I get this error:

```
Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set.
```

There is a builder.withLocalDatacenter() in the code.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I see, is that you're checking `dataCenter` for `null`, but you're not checking if it's empty.  So if `dataCenter` was equal to `""` (an empty string) it would get past the check for null, but still not apply a valid `dataCenter`.  Therefore, it's considered a better practice to validate strings in Java like this, instead:

```
if ( dataCenter != null && !dataCenter.isEmpty() ) {
    builder.withLocalDatacenter( dataCenter );
}
```

But I think the core problem here, is that `dataCenter` isn't getting a value.  I'd verify that.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code snippet you provided, `dataCenter` is undefined and hasn't been initialised. As a result the test condition doesn't get satisfied so `withLocalDatacenter()` doesn't get called.

In any case as the error message states, you need to explicitly tell the driver the name of the local DC so checking whether `dataCenter` is null or empty is bad practice.

Instead, you should always specify the data centre local to your app. For example:

```
datastax-java-driver {
  basic.load-balancing-policy {
    local-datacenter = DC1
  }
}
```

Of course when you're programatically building the session configuration,  *always* make a call to `withLocalDatacenter()`, for example:

```
CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder()
    .withLocalDatacenter("DC1")
    .build();
```

For details, see [Load balancing in the Java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/load_balancing/).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The code is used in a JDBC driver, which can connect to any Cassandra installations. I tested with a docker container, and assuming the user does not know the DataCenter name, I think it was better to skip the command .withLocalDatacenter(). But it seems this is mandatory. Does Cassandra has a default name for the dataCenters which I can use? Or maybe is any way to list the available dataCenter names?

Comment: Just run `nodetool status` to see details of your cluster including the DC names. Cheers!